# posting data from android to localhost

Tags: php, android, json, server, http-post

I am making a simple application where user responses for three questions are taken with the help of radio buttons and submitted to be stored in a database I have created on my localhost wamp server. 
i have no errors in my logcat but still the localhost database doesnot update data when I add entry to it.i.e the changes arnt visible. please help

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String URL_NEW_PREDICTION = "http://192.168.1.193/prediction/new_predict.php";
private Button btnAddPrediction;

String numOfGoal = "1";
String numOfCard = "1";
String diffOfPos = "1";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RadioGroup goal = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer1);

    goal.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.answer1A:
                    numOfGoal = "1";
                    break;
                case R.id.answer1B:
                    numOfGoal = "2";
                    break;
                case R.id.answer1C:
                    numOfGoal = "3";
                    break;

            }

        }
    });

    RadioGroup card = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer2);

    card.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.answer2A:
                    numOfCard = "1";
                    break;
                case R.id.answer2B:
                    numOfCard = "2";
                    break;
                case R.id.answer2C:
                    numOfCard = "3";
                    break;

            }
        }
    });

    RadioGroup pos = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answer3);

    pos.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.answer3A:
                    diffOfPos = "1";
                    break;
                case R.id.answer3B:
                    diffOfPos = "2";
                    break;
                case R.id.answer3C:
                    diffOfPos = "3";
                    break;

            }

        }
    });

    btnAddPrediction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    btnAddPrediction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new AddNewPrediction().execute(numOfGoal, numOfCard, diffOfPos);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class AddNewPrediction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String goalNo = arg[0];
        String cardNo = arg[1];
        String posDiff = arg[2];

        // Preparing post params
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("goalNo", goalNo));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cardNo", cardNo));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("posDiff", posDiff));

        serviceHandler serviceClient = new serviceHandler();

        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_NEW_PREDICTION,
                serviceHandler.POST, params);

       // Log.d("Create Prediction Request: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");
                // checking for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // new category created successfully
         //           Log.e("Prediction added successfully ",
           //                 "> " + jsonObj.getString("message"));
                } else {
             //       Log.e("Add Prediction Error: ",
               //             "> " + jsonObj.getString("message"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
           // Log.e("JSON Data", "JSON data error!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}}
```

serviceHandler

```
public class serviceHandler {
static InputStream is = null;
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public serviceHandler() {

}

public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}


public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                              List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;


        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {

            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        response = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     //   Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    return response;
}}
```

Config.php

```
<?php
 // Database configuration
 define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_NAME', 'wcdb');
?>
```

DbConnect.php

```
     <?php
     class DbConnect {  
    private $conn;        
    function __construct() {        
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
    }        
    function __destruct() {        
    $this->close();
    }        
    function connect() {        
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Config.php';                  
    $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die   (mysql_error());         
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());        
    // returing connection resource
    return $this->conn;
    }        
     // Close function          
    function close() {
    // close db connection
    mysql_close($this->conn);
    }
     }
    ?>
```

new_predict.php

```
       <?php
       include_once './DbConnect.php';
       function createNewPrediction() {
       $response = array();
       $goalNum = $_POST["goalNo"];
       $cardNum = $_POST["cardNo"];
       $posDiff = $_POST["posDiff"];
            $db = new DbConnect();
   // mysql query
    $query = "INSERT INTO prediction(goalNum,cardNum,posDiff) VALUES('$goalNum','$cardNum','$posDiff')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($result) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "Prediction added successfully!";
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Failed to add prediction!";
    }
   // echo json response
echo json_encode($response);
}
   createNewPrediction();
    ?>
```

Comment: what are you get from server response  like 200 or 400

Comment: Localhost? Your Android device is its own localhost. Every computer is its own localhost. So where are you lalking about?

Comment: `but still the localhost database doesnot update ` You should debug better. You should tell if the data is correctly sent by your Android app. Then you should examine and tell us if the data is correctly received by your php script. After that you should examine if the script tries to update the database. And so yes if that went ok. Then examine which data the script sends back. And finally examine if that is received by your Android app. So examine all steps and tell us and tell where something goes wrong.

Comment: I have mentioned that its a wamp server localhost

Comment: E/ASDASD: SENDING JSON: {"AdeviceId":"f7f46fe60e5a7da8","AdeviceType":"android","AversionId":72,"access_token":"aef4d2ecz","events":[]}
E/ASDASD: RECEIVING JSON: {"data":{"insertSuccess":1,"message":"Success"}}...... does this in my logcat proves that the data is sent and received by the android properly?

Comment: Which php file would have sent that? Its not sent by one of those files. Not that we can see. Why do you have three files? Which is used? Which log statement did print it?

Comment: +`have mentioned that its a wamp server localhost `. Localhost was nonsense. And still is nonsense. Please read my comment about localhost.so